# Wait for BackgroundTask to complete

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have a `BackgroundTask` which generates some text and then saves it as a file to a `LocalFolder`. I need to get this file with my main project (same VS solution) after it's been generated by the `BackgroundTask` and do some next work with it. The background task is triggered both manually by the user (via a "Reload" button) and every 15 mins by a `TimeTrigger`.

This is the relevant code snippet:

```
syncTrigger.RequestAsync(); 
articles = await getCachedArticles("");
```

How can I tell the `getCachedArticles` method to wait until after previous request finishes before running? Thank you very much!

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want `getCachedArticles("")` to only run after `syncTrigger.RequestAsync()` has completed? Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. Excuse me if my explanations aren't the best - I'm not daily English speaker. :)

Comment: No problem! Just wanted to make sure I was understanding the question. I'm not a native speaker either, I understand the struggle.

Comment: Can you show the signatures of `RequestAsync` & `getCachedArticles`?

Comment: For `getCachedArticles()` is it `private async Task<ObservableCollection<Article>> getCachedArticles(string sourceName)`.

Comment: And for `RequestAsync` is it `IAsyncOperation<ApplicationTriggerResult> RequestAsync()`?

Comment: `RequestAsync()` is predefined method for triggers. I don't know ho to get it's method signature. Sorry, maybe I just don't understand what do you mean.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand it correctly, what you need to do is to wait for [the `BackgroundTaskRegistration.Completed` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundtaskregistration.completed) to fire.

One approach would be to create an extension method that returns a `Task` that completes when the event fires:

```
public static Task<BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs> CompletedAsync(
    this BackgroundTaskRegistration registration)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs>();

    BackgroundTaskCompletedEventHandler handler = (s, e) =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(e);
        registration.Completed -= handler;
    };

    registration.Completed += handler;

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
var taskCompleted = registration.CompletedAsync();
await syncTrigger.RequestAsync();
await taskCompleted;
articles = await getCachedArticles("");
```

Note that the code calls `CompletedAsync()` *before* calling `RequestAsync()` to make sure the even handler is registered before the task is triggered, to avoid the race condition where the task completes before the handler is registered.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want your current context to wait for an asynchronous method to complete before continuing, you want to use the `await` keyword:

```
await syncTrigger.RequestAsync(); //the line below will not be executed until syncTrigger.RequestAsync() completes its task
articles = await getCachedArticles("");
```

I would recommend reading through the [await C# Reference Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) in order to get the full picture of how it works.

Comment: Unfortunelly no change even with "await". I have breakpoints on `articles = await getCachedArticles("");` and in BackgroundTask which I'm calling with syncTrigger.RequestAsync() and the `getCachedArticles()` is executed before the request calling.

Comment: What is the method signature of the `RequestAsync` method? It's very strange that `articles =...` line should run at all--`await syncTrigger...` should prevent that entirely, at least until it's finished running.

Comment: I would expect that too. Sorry, what do you mean by "method signature"?

Comment: Is syncTrigger a `DeviceTriggerResult`? By method signature I mean, for example `public returnType methodName(var input1, var input2)`.

Comment: I think it's `ApplicationTriggerResult` - `ApplicationTrigger syncTrigger = new ApplicationTrigger();`

Comment: The problem with this is that it waits until the the trigger request completes, not until the task finishes executing.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: [svick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35531663/197913) shows the best approach, I even wrote a [blog post](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20160227-GetNotifiedWhenABackgroundTaskCompletes.html) about it. Below is my original answer with a couple of indirect alternatives that might work for some cases.

As others have noted, awaiting `syncTrigger.RequestAsync()` won't help, although it is a good idea nevertheless. It will resume execution when the background task was succesfully triggered, and as such allow you to check if it failed for any reason.

You could create an [**app service**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187314.aspx) to make it work when you are triggering the background task from the application. App services behave similar to web services. They are running in a background task, but have request-response semantics.

In the background service you would need to handle the `RequestReceived` event:

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;
    appServiceconnection = details.AppServiceConnection;
    appServiceconnection.RequestReceived += OnRequestReceived;
}

private async void OnRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender,
    AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    var messageDeferral = args.GetDeferral();

    ValueSet arguments = args.Request.Message;
    ValueSet result = new ValueSet();

    // read values from arguments
    // do the processing
    // put data for the caller in result

    await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(result);
    messageDeferral.Complete(); 
}
```

In the client you can then call the app service:

```
var inventoryService = new AppServiceConnection();

inventoryService.AppServiceName = "from manifest";
inventoryService.PackageFamilyName = "from manifest";

var status = await inventoryService.OpenAsync();
var arguments = new ValueSet();
// set the arguments
var response = await inventoryService.SendMessageAsync(arguments);

if (response.Status == AppServiceResponseStatus.Success)
{
    var result = response.Message;
    // read data from the result
}
```

Check the [linked page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187314.aspx) for more information about app services.

You could call the same app service from the scheduled background task as well, but there would be no way to get notified when the processing was completed in this case.

Since you've mentioned that you're exchanging data via a file in `LocalFolder` your application could try **monitoring the changes** to that file instead:

```
private async Task Init()
{
    var storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var monitor = storageFolder.CreateFileQuery();
    monitor.ContentsChanged += MonitorContentsChanged;
    var files = await monitor.GetFilesAsync();
}

private void MonitorContentsChanged(IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args)
{
    // react to the file change - should mean the background task completed
}
```

As far as I know you can only monitor for all the changes in a folder and can't really determine what changed inside the event handler, so for your case it would be best to have a separate sub folder containing only the file saved by the background task once it completes. This way the event would only get raised when you need it to.

You'll have to check for yourself whether this approach works reliably enough for you, though.

Comment: I'm really excited of last opinion you wrote about - the change monitoring. I will try... :) The rest of seems to be too much complicated - I'm new in both UWP and C#. Thank you.

Comment: Did you overlook [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35531663/41071)? Or are you saying that it's wrong?

Comment: @svick I don't think your answer works for the scheduled task that would automatically trigger every 15 mins?

Comment: @DamirArh Why not? It's still the same background task, just a different trigger, so the same `BackgroundTaskRegistration` should work for both.

Comment: @svick Hm... as long as you re-register it on application startup, to attach a new event handler (which is a good idea any way), it might work, indeed. Of course, the `TaskCompletionSource` will only trigger once in your case, but that's already an implementation detail. You got me curious, I'll actually try this out in the near future.

Comment: @svick `Completed` event indeed works great for all background tasks. I wrote a [blogpost](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20160227-GetNotifiedWhenABackgroundTaskCompletes.html) about it. And upvoted [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35531663/197913).

Answer (score -3):

You need to wait the RequestAsync method completed with the result
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.devicetriggerresult

after that I suggest to wait a few seconds with task.delay and try to get the data.

Update: 
 When you have the device trigger result  you need to check this result before to try to get the data after that you can suppose that you have the data saved. I suggested before to use Task.Delay just to wait a few seconds to be sure all data is saved because sometimes the process take some milliseconds more than is expected. I did this because we don't have an event like TriggerCompleted  I needed to create my own approach. 
I did this before in my app and it works very well.

Comment: You really should go back an change your app. I don't think this is a very robust solution at all.

Comment: there is not a robust solution for now